# 2N2222 NPN Transistor, no current flowing through collector

Tags: transistors, npn, 12v, 5v

I have a 2N2222 NPN Transistor wired up in the most basic common emitter setting (emitter grounded, base hooked up with a 1k resistor to 5V, collector connected to load and load connected to +12V). Ground is common with the two voltages, but when i try to do anything, even short the collector with the +12V, i get no current flow. I measured with a multimeter, and there's indeed 12v between collector and +12V, but i can't even power an LED. I'm a beginner so i honestly don't know anymore.

Comment: You may need to show us pictures of what you are actually doing in order to write your words, above. When you say "no current flow," for example, that's ***your*** conclusion about a situation. But I don't trust your conclusions. So I need to see what you are actually doing and observing and ***how*** you are making that conclusion. Words alone won't cut it because your lack of knowledge means that your interpretations are suspect. Also, you should use a resistor in series with an LED!! More reasons about why I'm worried.

Comment: @jonk I checked with my multimeter in the ampere setting. I know that i need a resistor, but i know that the LED is working because i checked multiple times with normal 5V. I'm also certain that i used the ampmeter correctly because i've done that multiple times before.

Comment: @Veestire The ampere setting (assuming you really mean Amps!) isn't something that a 2N2222 BJT can readily handle at the collector. You are basically shorting the collector to the +12 V supply rail. That is NOT a good thing to do.

Comment: I'm guessing your transistor is probably fried.

Comment: According to my multimeter measurements, all my transistors are dead (at least according to what someone said online - 0.45 to 0.9 voltage drop across base and emitter - i get 0.02 or OL and like 2 across base and collector, or OL aswell)

Comment: I hope i measured it wrong, but if they're really all dead, what's the potential cause? How did i kill them? Could not putting a resistor on base kill them? I think i did that with basically all of them before, so that could be the cause.

Comment: If you short the collector to 12V, with 5mA base bias, you shouldn't expect any collector current afterwards. But if there's really 12V between collector and +12V supply, the load has gone open circuit too.

Comment: Yes. The base is like a diode. For a 2n2222 silicone transistor with a target forward voltage drop of 0.7V putting 5V across is will drop all 5V across it with a matching current, frying the base diode. Same for putting 12V without a load across the collector. Imagine its a very small resistor. As it drops the full 12V the current will be very high and the resistance will cause it to heat up and burn out. (This is just a bad analogy). In short try with a fresh transistor and don't forget to include the base resistor and load.

Comment: Okay, i used a fresh PNP transistor and now it works but i have an another question - is it supposed to heat up to the point of burning my fingers with just 130mA? Do i need to cool it somehow?

Comment: @Veestire Give us a schematic of what you're doing.

Comment: This is my first time making a schematic, so it might be wrong, but i think this is how i made the circuit. https://imgur.com/a/GqPrH5C

Comment: it could be that your load is  damaged, post a picture with voltage measurements.

Comment: My load's fine, i can connect it straight to 12V or any other voltage source and it works fine.

Comment: 2N2222 or SS8550 ? because trhe SS8850 is PNP and works with current in the opposite direction to 2N2222

Comment: I might just make a new post because it's getting confusing now. I decided that all my 2N2222's are dead, so i tried an SS8550 and it works but gets really hot, so i asked if that's normal.